# Regex - matching while ignoring some characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to max a sequence of numbers that is 5 digits long or over, but I ignore any spaces, dashes, parens, or hashes when doing that analysis. Here's what I have so far.

```
(\d|\(|\)|\s|#|-){5,}
```

The problem with this is that this will match any sequence of 5 characters including those characters I want to ignore, so something like "#123 " would match. While I do want to ignore the # and space character, I still need the number itself to be 5 digits or more in order to qualify at a match.

To be clear, these would match:

```
1-2-3-4-5
123 45
2(134)   5
```

Bonus points if the matching begins and ends with a number rather than with one of those "special characters" I am excluding.
Any tips for doing this kind of matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood requirements right you can use:

```
^\d(?:[()\s#-]*\d){4,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB1wK1/2)

It always matches a digit at start. Then it is followed by 4 or more of a non-capturing group i.e. `(?:[()\s#-]*\d)` which means 0 or more of any listed special character followed by a digit.

Comment: Tested all the cases I can think of and it works perfectly. I'll just be over here trying to figure out why it works. Thanks.

Comment: It works because `\d` is used right after `^` and right before `$` thus eliminating the case of any non-digit at start or end.

Answer (score 2):

So just repeat a digit, followed by any other sequence of allowed characters 5 or more times:

```
^(\d[()\s#-]*){5,}$
```

You can ensure it ends on a digit if you subtract one of the repetitions and add an explicit digit at the end:

```
^(\d[()\s#-]*){4,}\d$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can suggest non-digits with \D so et would be something like:

```
(\d\D*){5,}
```

[Here](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/) is a guide.

Comment: The OP was specific about which characters could be ignored. For example, '1a1a1a1a1a' =~ /(\d\D*){5,}/ #=> 0`, but letters cannot be ignored, so that should return `nil`.